# How to make scroll work in just one element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a webpage which has an image on top. When the user scrolls up, the image is supposed to go up a bit while the other elements are blocked. As soon as that image reaches the desired position, the rest of the elements can scroll up or down as well. This is the main idea: users scrolls, image moves. User keeps scrolling, elements move as well.
This is what i have so far:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(event){
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (st > lastScrollTop){
   $("#ballonImg").css("top", "-=5px");
    } else {
      $("#ballonImg").css("top", "+=5px");
    }
   lastScrollTop = st;
 });
```

And the Html:

```
 <div id="top">
   <div id="images">
    <img id="ballonImg"src="http://i.imgur.com/rMm5gCy.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/l3GI35D.png"/>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="cenas"></div>
```

Comment: jsfiddle would be great

Comment: This is my codepen: http://codepen.io/Nicki_Reds/pen/jqGeEm

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS positioning. Position fixed, absolute, relative, and static can all be useful for this purpose. You should also consider setting the unmoving image as the background of the div, and have the other image inside of it, but with a z-index set to 2 (or anything greater than 1).

Answer (score 0):

I have created this and it works just as you described.

I am using `jquery-mousewheel` to get the `mousewheel` event and used `deltaY` to check if the user is scrolling up or down. Then used the `deltaFactor` to determine how much the user have wheeled. Used that value to change the `top` value of the image.

I also kept a `minTop` and `maxTop` values to keep the image between this range. Then when the image reaches the `minTop` value I have enabled the overflow on the page so that the page scrolls as usual.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var minTop = -200;
  var maxTop = 50;
  $(window).on('mousewheel', function(event) {
    var top = Number($('.imgHolder').css('top').replace('px', ''));
    console.log(top, minTop)
    if (top + event.deltaFactor * (event.deltaY < 0 ? -1 : 1) >= minTop) {
      $('#container').addClass('overflowHidden');
      top = top + event.deltaFactor * (event.deltaY < 0 ? -1 : 1);
      top = top < minTop ? minTop : top;
      top = top > maxTop ? maxTop : top;
      $('.imgHolder').css('top', top);
    } else {
      $('#container').removeClass('overflowHidden');
    }
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
}
.imgHolder {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 10%;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
#container.overflowHidden {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" class="overflowHidden">
    <div class="content">
      On July 1, 1963, Project MAC (the Project on Mathematics and Computation, later backronymed to Multiple Access Computer, Machine Aided Cognitions, or Man and Computer) was launched with a $2 million grant from the Defense Advanced Research Projects Agency
      (DARPA). Project MAC's original director was Robert Fano of MIT's Research Laboratory of Electronics (RLE). Fano decided to call MAC a "project" rather than a "laboratory" for reasons of internal MIT politics—if MAC had been called a laboratory,
      then it would have been more difficult to raid other MIT departments for research staff. The program manager responsible for the DARPA grant was J.C.R. Licklider, who had previously been at MIT conducting research in RLE, and would later succeed
      Fano as director of Project MAC. Project MAC would become famous for groundbreaking research in operating systems, artificial intelligence, and the theory of computation. Its contemporaries included Project Genie at Berkeley, the Stanford Artificial
      Intelligence Laboratory, and (somewhat later) University of Southern California's (USC's) Information Sciences Institute. An "AI Group" including Marvin Minsky (the director), John McCarthy (who invented Lisp) and a talented community of computer
      programmers was incorporated into the newly formed Project MAC. It was interested principally in the problems of vision, mechanical motion and manipulation, and language, which they view as the keys to more intelligent machines. In the 1950s - 1970s
      the AI Group shared a computer room with a computer (initially a PDP-6, and later a PDP-10) for which they built a time-sharing operating system called ITS.[citation needed] The early Project MAC community included Fano, Minsky, Licklider, Fernando
      J. Corbató, and a community of computer programmers and enthusiasts among others who drew their inspiration from former colleague John McCarthy. These founders envisioned the creation of a computer utility whose computational power would be as reliable
      as an electric utility. To this end, Corbató brought the first computer time-sharing system, CTSS, with him from the MIT Computation Center, using the DARPA funding to purchase an IBM 7094 for research use. One of the early focuses of Project MAC
      would be the development of a successor to CTSS, Multics, which was to be the first high availability computer system, developed as a part of an industry consortium including General Electric and Bell Laboratories. In 1966, Scientific American featured
      Project MAC in the September thematic issue devoted to computer science, that was later published in book form. At the time, the system was described as having approximately 100 TTY terminals, mostly on campus but with a few in private homes. Only
      30 users could be logged in at the same time. The project enlisted students in various classes to use the terminals simultaneously in problem solving, simulations, and multi-terminal communications as tests for the multi-access computing software
      being developed.</div>

    <div class="imgHolder">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Stata_Center1.jpg/800px-Stata_Center1.jpg" />
    </div>
</body>
</div>

</html>
```